# Why doubling the cube can be described as finding the intersection of the parabole $y=\frac{1}{2} x^2$ and the hyperbola $xy=1$?

Tags: geometry

I have read that doubling the cube can be described as finding the intersection of the parabole $y=\frac{1}{2} x^2$ and the hyperbola $xy=1$. It can be seen that the solution of the equations is $x^3=2$, which is the doubling the cube problem. However, what is the geometrical intuition behind the the parabole and the hyperbola?

Comment: This is Menaechmus's solution, see here: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Doubling_the_cube/

Comment: Thank you for the link!